# Order in taking out values in a panel data set R

Tags: r, database, plm

I'm using an unbalanced panel dataset in R plm package. Since there is one missing variable for 2010 and there are some zero values for some variables, I proceeded in two steps:

```r
#puts the panel data into a pdata.frame
dd <- pdata.frame(panel, index = c ('UF', 'year'))

#Takes out the year 2010
year <- dd$year
dd <- dd[year!=2010, ]

#Takes out values where population equals zero
pop <- dd$pop
dd_1 <- dd[pop!= 0,]

#Renames all variables
PIB <- dd_1$PIB
DT <- dd_1$despesa
RT <- dd_1$receita
#.....

#Runs an OLS model
ols_model <- plm(log(PIB) ~ mortinf + log(prod) + op  + log(DT) + Gini + I(log(DT)*Gini) + log(RT) + log(pop),  data = dd_1, model = "pooling")
summary (ols_model)
```

However, when I did as above, I couldn't plot the values of the variables in graphs (because dd_1$GDP, for example, isn't considered a vector). So I've changed the data manipulation order: Instead of putting the data into a data.frame, I first took out the values from the panel and then indicated in the OLS model what were the indexes for year and unit.

```r
year <- panel$year
dd <- panel[year!=2010,]

#Takes out observations where pop == 0
pop <- dd$pop
dd_1 <- dd[pop!=0, ]

#Renames variables

GDP <- dd_1$GDP
DT <- dd_1$DT
#...
#This way I could plot, for example, GDP x DT in a graph
#Then I ran an OLS model:
ols_model <- plm(log(PIB) ~ mortinf + log(prod) + op  + log(DT) + Gini + I(log(DT)*Gini) + log(RT) + log(pop),  
data = dd_1, model = "pooling", index = c ('UF', 'year'))
summary (ols_model)

#But it gave different results than the first OLS!
```

In my understanding, both models should have outputed the same results, but they were very different. Could anyone please help me? What is the right way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a bit confused. Firstly, there is no need to create a new variable every time you subset. You can use ```panel[panel$year!=2010,]```. When you write "rename variables" you are actually creating new vectors, you arent renaming them. I think it would good practice to use only variables that are in pdata.frame object when you run plm. Also, it is a bit difficult to help if you dont provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've made a reproducible question, if you could still help me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600824/how-to-correctly-take-out-zero-observations-in-panel-data-in-r